# how to unlock exe file that created by folder lock portable software

Tags: file-unlocking

I have password protected wallet that created by folder lock portable.

I forget my password and wallet extension is "Application.EXE how can I unlock it without the password?

Comment: If you password lock something then you shouldn't forget it. Whatever it is consider it lost.

Answer (score 1):

#### Folder Lock Recover Password

Use the following procedure:

> **Folder Lock Recover Password**
>
> So you have forgotten your password. No need to worry!
>
> If you are a registered user, simply enter the serial number you
> received after your purchase in the Master Password field.
>
> [image]

Source: [Recover your password easily - Folder Lock](https://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/forgotten-password/)

If you are **not** a registered user you need to order the full version to get a serial key

Comment: But getting a serial key after the fact would allow them to unlock any previously locked file? Not likely to be the case.

Comment: What kind of stupid software allows both a password and an easy decipherable product key? All this tells me is the folder is either not actually locked in a secure way or it's encrypted in an way that is easily bypassed.

Comment: I love how their website *almost* looks professional until you see the "lorem ipsum" that is directly copied from from any number of "generator" websites without actually bothering to check that what they were copying was *actual* lorem ipsum. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gpur.png

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the password or the serial number from when you got
Folder Lock, then you risk losing the locked folder by using hacks.
You should really make an effort to remember your password.

The following method is taken from the article
[How to Recover Files from Folder Lock Without Password Step-by-Step](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-files-from-folder-lock-without-password.html).

Out of the three methods in the article, the first you already know
and the third sounds risky, so the following is a summary of Method 2.

**Method 2. Remove Password from Locked Files by Uninstall Folder Lock**

- Open `regedit`
- Go to key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/NewSoftware's/Folder Lock/Uninstall`
- Double-click the item `Uninstall` and change its value data from
  `1` to `0`
- Click OK and exit `regedit`
- Open Task Manager and terminate any running task that seems
  associated with Folder Lock
- Run *Settings > Apps > Apps & Features*
- Find and click Folder Lock
- Click twice Uninstall and wait for it to finish
- If everything worked fine, then your folder is now accessible.

See the linked article for more details with screenshots.